# Consulta Mysql, filtrar

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con Personas y roles, y quiero sacar en una select a las personas que no tengan el Rol de Jefe departamento.

El problema es que si tiene el rol usuario también lo muestra y quiero que en el momento que tenga el rol de jefe no se muestre.

```
Select Id_usuario 
from union_pers_rols
where Id_rol != 'Jefe Departamento'
```

Tabla union_pers_rols 2 columnas: Id_usuario (Es un nombre) Id_rol, Tiene el (rol) de esa persona

Tengo que sacar todas las personas que no tengan el rol "Jefe Departamento".
El problema es que hay usuarios con más de 1 rol en esa tabla " Usuario "
Entonces me saca el nombre de esa persona porque lo está cogiendo por el rol Usuario

Antes de la select : 
    Id_usuario
    Id_rol

```
edu@
Usuario 

jaime@
Jefe Departamento  

jaime@
Root 

jaime@
Usuario

nose@
Usuario 

pass@
Usuario
```

Después de la select

```
Id_usuario
edu@
jaime@
jaime@
nose@
pass@
```

Como se puede ver me saca a Jaime@ porque también tiene otros roles =(

Comment: Hola EduBw. Sé que ya hicistes una pregunta respecto a estas tablas, pero esta pregunta por sí sola no está clara. Por favor describe claramente las tablas implicadas (nombre + columnas), danos un ejemplo de datos en tus tablas, el resultado obtenido + el resultado deseado.

Comment: Ya está modificado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo veo raro que quieres obtener una lista de usuarios usando una tabla donde los registros para usuarios pueden aparecer varias veces según sus rols. ¿No tienes una tabla separada `usuarios` también?

De cualquier forma, necesitas una claúsula `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct r.Id_usuario
  from union_pers_rols r
 where not exists (select null
                     from union_pers_rols j
                    where j.Id_usuario = r.Id_usuario
                      and j.Id_rol = 'Jefe Departamento')
```

Pero si tienes una tabla dedicada para los usuarios, entonces la consulta mas lógica sería algo como:

```
select *
  from usuarios u
 where not exists (select null
                     from union_pers_rols r
                    where r.Id_usuario = u.Id_usuario
                      and r.Id_rol = 'Jefe Departamento')
```

Comment: Tengo 3 tablas

La tabla de usuarios con los datos, la tabla de roles, con los roles que existen y la tabla union_per_rols que sale de M:M En el modelo relacional.

Comment: Entonces lo ideal sería la segunda consulta. Esto te evita tener que agregar un `DISTINCT` como lo hice con la primera consulta. Por en esa primera consulta, sin el `DISTINCT`, aunque te devuelva la lista correcta de usuarios, puede devolverte duplicados.

Comment: SI, las 2 consultas funcionan, muchas gracias, tengo enormes problemas en SQL cuando se trata de buscar algo que " no esté ". Hacer consultas de cosas que están haces las inner join y sale fácil , pero buscar las diferencias y esas cosas se me da como el ... XD GRACIAS !